# io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException in method marked with @Transactional

Tags: java, transactions, micronaut, micronaut-data

My team is working in micronaut 3.2.0 and using micronaut-data-jdbc.  Currently, I'm seeing this error summarized below below at the code location listed below.  Basically, I'm getting a NoTransactionException exception three lines into a method that carries the annotation to start a transaction.

Any suggestions for debugging and/or resolution will be most appreciated.  I tried enabling trace level log output while the test case ran, but this part of micronaut-data (io.micronaut.transaction) doesn't seem to have many trace entries coded.

```
io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:65)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnection$Intercepted.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.oracle.gbu.gaes.monitoring.MonitoringService$MetricContext.reportTimedExec(MonitoringService.java:270)
    at com.oracle.gbu.gaes.monitoring.MonitoringService$MyHandlerForConnection.invoke(MonitoringService.java:567)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.gbu.gts.provisioning.dao.DatabasesDAO.createDatabase(DatabasesDAO.java:50)
    at com.oracle.gbu.gts.provisioning.logic.DatabasesManager.createDatabase(DatabasesManager.java:123)
    at com.oracle.gbu.gts.provisioning.dao.DatabaseDAOTest.setup(DatabaseDAOTest.java:49)

...

    Suppressed: io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:65)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnection$Intercepted.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.oracle.gbu.gaes.monitoring.MonitoringService$MyHandlerForConnection.invoke(MonitoringService.java:585)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.oracle.gbu.gts.provisioning.dao.DatabasesDAO.createDatabase(DatabasesDAO.java:49)
        ... 64 more
    Caused by: io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.exceptions.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: No current JDBC Connection found. Consider wrapping this call in transactional boundaries.
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:135)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:93)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:63)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.exceptions.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: No current JDBC Connection found. Consider wrapping this call in transactional boundaries.
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:135)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:93)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:63)
    ... 74 more
```

in this block of code in DatabasesDAO.java:

```
  @Transactional(rollbackOn = {java.lang.Exception.class})
  public Database createDatabase(Database database, boolean updateLastReset)
    throws Exception
  {
    // change to merge with reset timestamp update optional
    
    try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement merge_db = connection.prepareStatement(MERGE_DB))    <== line 50
    {
```

Comment: step 1 would be to update to the most recent Micronaut (v3.2.5) just in case this is a fixed bug

Comment: can you show your complete classes including imports, both of the  DAO as well as of the calling method?

Comment: Are you creating an instance of the `DatabasesDAO` class or is Micronaut creating the instance for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `javax.transaction.Transactional`.